# $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is a cyclic group?

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

I think that $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ isn't a cyclic group becuase we don't have any $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ that can create the group $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

I'm right?

Thank you!

Comment: if it is, it is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: You need to justify that. Why can't any $(a, b)$ generate the group?

Comment: Can an infinite cyclic group have elements of finite order?

Comment: @AymanHourieh - Tell me if I'm right:
For $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ if we will take $(a,1)$ we can't make the second element 0 (Just if we multiply by 0 and them we we will get $(0,0)$). And from the same reason we can't take $(a,0)$ because then we can't make the second element 1. (Just if we multiply by 1, and then we will get $(1,1)$).

I'm right or I miss something?

Comment: @DietrichBurde - I didn't understand the proof...

Comment: It is not right. You can make the second element $0$: $(a,1) + (a,1) = (2a, 0)$. Unless you mean that you can't get $(a,0)$. Your argument requires more justification either way.

Comment: Your argument doesn't work for the reason outlined by NotAwake. It can be shown that $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z_2$ can't be generated by one element, but an argument like the one given by Daniel Fischer is easier. What's the order of every non-identity element in an infinite cyclic group? What's the order of $(0, 1)$?

Comment: @AymanHourieh - Can you give me a hint for the proof?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is the only infinite cyclic group, up to isomorphism. Isomorphisms preserve orders of elements. With this and Ayman Hourieh's comment, you should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

In very short: suppose

$$\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z_2=\langle\;(a,b)\;\rangle\;,\;\;a\in\Bbb Z\;,\;b\in\Bbb Z_2$$

Well, then how'd you solve $\;(a+1,b)=n(a,b)\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb Z\;?$

Comment: Thank you, but I don't under stand: $\;(a+1,b)=n(a,b)\;$ What is this equation? 
Can you explain me please?
Thank you!

Comment: If the group is cyclic then it is generated by one single element, say by $\;(a,b)\;,\;a\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;b\in\Bbb Z_2\;$ , right? But then undoubtedly the lelement $\;(a+1,b)\;$ *also* belongs to the group and thus it must be a (n integer) multiple of the generator, by the definition of cyclic (additively written) group.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: I know that this question will be funny, but what is the meaning of $\mathbb{Z}/2\;$? (maybe we mark it different).